# Unable to see the line segment on plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot 1000 line segments on one single plot using the following code

```
corr1 = [round(pic.autocorr(i),4) for i in range(1,1001)]

index = range(1,1001)
y_points = zip(index, corr1)
x_points = zip(index, [ 0 for i in range(1,1001)])

line_collection = []

for i in range(0,1000):
    temp = []
    temp.append(x_points[i])
    temp.append(y_points[i])
    line_collection.append(temp)

lc = mc.LineCollection(line_collection, color = 'r', linewidth = 1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,6))
ax.cla()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.set_ylabel('autocorrelation')
ax.set_xlabel('lag')
ax.set_xticks([range(1,1001,50)])
ax.set_yticks([ x/10.0 for x in range(-10, 11,1)])
plt.show()
```

What I get is error message like

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is     ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I think the error is caused by these two lines

```
ax.set_xticks([range(1,1001,50)])
ax.set_yticks([ x/10.0 for x in range(-10, 11,1)])
```

Since when I comment out these two lines, the error message won't show up. But I still don't know what's the issue causing the error in these two lines.
And I am still unable to plot the figure I want. What I can get is 
[image]

I think the data has already been plotted on the figure, since when I put my mouse on the graph, the value of x and y will show up on the screen. I really don't know what's the exact reason the plot won't show up.

Comment: Try `ax.set_xticks(range(1,1001,50))` without the additional list.

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot!! I've spent hours on this! T.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is produced by the line `ax.set_xticks([range(1,1001,50)])`, which creates a list inside a list. Use `ax.set_xticks(range(1,1001,50))` instead.

The fact that you don't see the lines may be caused by the lines not being inside the viewing range. This is because the viewing range does not autoscale to the artists inside the axes.

You might therefore want to set the limits `ax.set_xlim(1,951)`, `ax.set_ylim(-1,1)` first.